# How do I correctly reproject a geodataframe with multiple geometry columns?

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

In [the geopandas documentation](https://geopandas.org/data_structures.html) it says that

> A `GeoDataFrame` may also contain other columns with geometrical (shapely) objects, but only one column can be the active geometry at a time. To change which column is the active geometry column, use the `set_geometry` method.

I'm wondering how to use such a GeoDataFrame if the goal is to flexibly **reproject** the geometrical data in these various columns to one or more other coordinate reference systems. Here's what I tried.

#### First try

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

crs_lonlat = 'epsg:4326'        #geometries entered in this crs (lon, lat in degrees)
crs_new = 'epsg:3395'           #geometries needed in (among others) this crs
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(crs=crs_lonlat)      
gdf['geom1'] = [Point(9,53), Point(9,54)]     
gdf['geom2'] = [Point(8,63), Point(8,64)]

#Working: setting geometry and reprojecting for first time.
gdf = gdf.set_geometry('geom1')
gdf = gdf.to_crs(crs_new)   #geom1 is reprojected to crs_new, geom2 still in crs_lonlat
gdf
Out: 
                             geom1          geom2
0  POINT (1001875.417 6948849.385)  POINT (8 63)
1  POINT (1001875.417 7135562.568)  POINT (8 64)

gdf.crs
Out: 'epsg:3395'
```

So far, so good. Things go off the rails if I want to set `geom2` as the geometry column, and reproject that one as well:

```
#Not working: setting geometry and reprojecting for second time.
gdf = gdf.set_geometry('geom2')     #still in crs_lonlat...
gdf.crs                             #...but this still says crs_new...
Out: 'epsg:3395'

gdf = gdf.to_crs(crs_new)           #...so this doesn't do anything! (geom2 unchanged)
gdf
Out: 
                             geom1                      geom2
0  POINT (1001875.417 6948849.385)  POINT (8.00000 63.00000)
1  POINT (1001875.417 7135562.568)  POINT (8.00000 64.00000)
```

Ok, so, apparently, the `.crs` attribute of the `gdf` is not reset to its original value when changing the column that serves as the geometry - it seems, the crs is not stored for the individual columns. If that is the case, the only way I see to use reprojection with this dataframe, is to backtrack: start --> select column as geometry --> reproject gdf to crs_new --> use/visualize/... --> reproject gdf back to crs_lonlat --> goto start. This is not usable if I want to visualise both columns in one figure.

#### Second try

My second attempt was, to store the `crs` with each column separately, by changing the corresponding lines in the script above to:

```
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
gdf['geom1'] = gpd.GeoSeries([Point(9,53), Point(9,54)], crs=crs_lonlat)
gdf['geom2'] = gpd.GeoSeries([Point(8,63), Point(8,64)], crs=crs_lonlat)
```

However, it soon became clear that, though initialised as a `GeoSeries`, these columns are normal `pandas` `Series`, and don't have a `.crs` attribute the same way `GeoSeries` do:

```
gdf['geom1'].crs
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'crs'

s = gpd.GeoSeries([Point(9,53), Point(9,54)], crs=crs_lonlat)
s.crs
Out: 'epsg:4326'
```

**Is there something I'm missing here?**

Is the only solution, to decide on the 'final' crs beforehand - and do all the reprojecting before adding the columns? Like so...

```
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(crs=crs_new)
gdf['geom1'] = gpd.GeoSeries([Point(9,53), Point(9,54)], crs=crs_lonlat).to_crs(crs_new)
gdf['geom2'] = gpd.GeoSeries([Point(8,63), Point(8,64)], crs=crs_lonlat).to_crs(crs_new)
#no more reprojecting done/necessary/possible! :/
```

...and then, when another crs is needed, rebuild the entire `gdf` from scratch? That can't be the way this was intended to be used.

(Full disclosure: I posted this question on stack overflow, but it wasn't getting much love/attention over there.)

## EDIT: Answer - or workaround

`geopandas` does not accommodate this use case at the moment. My workaround is to not use a `GeoDataFrame`, but rather combine a normal `pandas` `DataFrame`, for the non-shapely data, with several `geopandas` `GeoSeries`, for the shapely geometry data. The `GeoSeries` each have their own crs and can be effortlessly reprojected whenever necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case of GeoDataFrame, CRS in GeoPandas is stored on the level of GeoDataFrame, not individual GeoSeries (as of version 0.7.0, there is a discussion to change it). At this moment, I think that your solution of reprojecting GeoSeries and then assigning then to GeoDataFrame is the best solution, although admittedly not very elegant. Feel free to express your thoughts on it on GitHub: https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1193

Comment: Thanks for your answer - that confirms that it's not something I'm using incorrectly; the package just doesn't accomodate for it at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/749#issuecomment-398239336) helped me.

```
for column in gdf.columns:
    gdf = gdf.set_geometry(column).to_crs(crs_new)
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and in my case it was not possible to maintain geometry and attributes separately.

So, in my case, I had a GeoDataframe (called `gds`) with 2 geometry columns `start_geometry` and `end_geometry`. I did the following:

```
gdf = gdf.to_crs("EPSG:32618")
gdf.crs="EPSG:4326"
gdf = gdf.set_geometry("end_geometry")
gdf = .to_crs("EPSG:32618")
```

Note that, by setting `gdf.crs` manually, I tricked it into thinking the data was unprojected. So, when I changed the active geometry column and tried projection again, it changed the projection for the second geometry column.